# High school Math team questions!!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

After successive discounts of 25%, 20%, 37.5% and 33(1/3)% are applied to the original price of an item, the final price of that item is the same as if the original price had been discounted once by n%. Compute n.
Is the answer 66.625.
If not, please teach me how to approach to the right answer!!
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: This is easier if you calculate the reduced prices (instead of just the discounts), and then translate the final answer to a discount at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Lets call the original amount $A$. Then, after the first discount the price would become:$$A\times(1-0.25)=a\times0.75$$The second discount should now be applied to this new amount so after the second discount the price would become:$$A\times0.75\times(1-0.2)=A\times0.75\times0.8=A\times0.6$$This means that the first two discounts are equivalent to $(1-0.6)=0.4=40$%. Keep applying this rule until you end up with something like:$$A\times r$$The equivalent discount is then $(1-r)\times100$%

Comment: I still get 66.625 by ur way.

Comment: is it right?I might did st wrong throughout.

Comment: No it is not correct - please show your full working so that I can spot where you may have made a mistake